# Trouble creating DefaultDict in Dataclass

Tags: python-3.x, defaultdict, python-dataclasses

I am having trouble setting up a simple dataclass using  a new defaultdict(dict).

If I tell the factory to use 'dict' as below , instantiation fails  with *typerror collection.defaultdict object is not callable*

```
from collections import defaultdict
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class ResultSet:
    changed: bool = False
    mqttdata:  defaultdict(dict) = field(default_factory=defaultdict(dict)) # does not work!
```

It does sorta work using **field(default_factory=defaultdict)** but then my code will fail later when it encounters missing keys - presumably because defaultdict was not set up for dict.

How do I properly set up a new defaultdict(dict) in a dataclass?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have a few problems with the code and how you are using `dataclasses` currently:

- Type generics in annotations need to be specified through square brackets `[]` generally, so `default[dict]` instead of `defaultdict(dict)` for example.
- The `default_factory` argument to `dataclasses.field()` needs to be a no-arg callable which returns a new object with default values set. For example, assuming you have a nested dataclass `Inner` which specifies defaults for all fields, you *could* use `default_factory=Inner` to create a new `Inner` object each time the main dataclass is instantiated.

  Note that the `default_factory` argument is mainly useful for mutable types
  such as `set`, `list`, and `dict`, so that the same object isn't
  shared (and potentially mutated) between dataclass instances.

---

Putting it all together, here is the working code which sets a default value for a field of type `defaultdict[dict]`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class ResultSet:
    changed: bool = False
    mqttdata: defaultdict[dict] = field(default_factory=lambda: defaultdict(dict))  # works!


print(ResultSet())
```

---

In Python versions earlier than 3.9, which is when [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) was introduced, you'll need to add the following import at the top so that any type annotations are *lazy-evaluated*:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

Comment: Thanks - works like a champ!  Note for others, this solution will not work in 3.7.4 without the future  annotations import -  it will choke with type object is not subscriptable

Comment: Are we forced through the field() syntax when we need to enforce a default factory?